# Android save or insert MMS in content provider programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-contentprovider, mms, android-mms

I am trying code described below, I got it from internet. It inserts rows in content provider(mmssms.db) properly but MMS is not shown Native Messaging App.

thread_id 11 is already present in my content provider so I am using thread_id 11.

```
public static Uri insert(Context context, String to, String subject, byte[] imageBytes)
{
    try
    {           
        Uri destUri = Uri.parse("content://mms");

        // Get thread id
        //Set<String> recipients = new HashSet<String>();
        //recipients.addAll(Arrays.asList(to));
        long thread_id = getOrCreateThreadId(context, to);
        Log.e(">>>>>>>", "Thread ID is " + thread_id);

        // Create a dummy sms
        ContentValues dummyValues = new ContentValues();
        dummyValues.put("thread_id", thread_id);
        dummyValues.put("body", "Dummy SMS body.");
        Uri dummySms = context.getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://sms/"), dummyValues);

        // Create a new message entry
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        ContentValues mmsValues = new ContentValues();
        mmsValues.put("thread_id", thread_id);
        mmsValues.put("date", now/1000L);
        mmsValues.put("msg_box", Mms.MESSAGE_BOX_OUTBOX);
        //mmsValues.put("m_id", System.currentTimeMillis());
        mmsValues.put("read", 1);
        mmsValues.put("sub", subject);
        mmsValues.put("sub_cs", 106);
        mmsValues.put("ct_t", "application/vnd.wap.multipart.related");
        mmsValues.put("exp", imageBytes.length);
        mmsValues.put("m_cls", "personal");
        mmsValues.put("m_type", 128); // 132 (RETRIEVE CONF) 130 (NOTIF IND) 128 (SEND REQ)
        mmsValues.put("v", 19);
        mmsValues.put("pri", 129);
        mmsValues.put("tr_id", "T"+ Long.toHexString(now));
        mmsValues.put("resp_st", 128);

        // Insert message
        Uri res = context.getContentResolver().insert(destUri, mmsValues);
        String messageId = res.getLastPathSegment().trim();
        Log.e(">>>>>>>", "Message saved as " + res);

        // Create part
        createPart(context, messageId, imageBytes);


        createAddr(context, messageId, to);


        //res = Uri.parse(destUri + "/" + messageId);

        // Delete dummy sms
        context.getContentResolver().delete(dummySms, null, null);

        return res;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

private static Uri createPart(Context context, String id, byte[] imageBytes) throws Exception
{
    ContentValues mmsPartValue = new ContentValues();
    mmsPartValue.put("mid", id);
    mmsPartValue.put("ct", "image/png");
    mmsPartValue.put("cid", "<" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ">");
    Uri partUri = Uri.parse("content://mms/" + id + "/part");
    Uri res = context.getContentResolver().insert(partUri, mmsPartValue);
    Log.e(">>>>>>>", "Part uri is " + res.toString());

    // Add data to part
    OutputStream os = context.getContentResolver().openOutputStream(res);
    ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(imageBytes);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
    for (int len=0; (len=is.read(buffer)) != -1;)
    {
        os.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    os.close();
    is.close();

    return res;
}

private static Uri createAddr(Context context, String id, String addr) throws Exception
{
    ContentValues addrValues = new ContentValues();
    addrValues.put("address", addr);
    addrValues.put("charset", "106");
    addrValues.put("type", 151); // TO
    Uri addrUri = Uri.parse("content://mms/"+ id +"/addr");
    Uri res = context.getContentResolver().insert(addrUri, addrValues);
    Log.e(">>>>>>>", "Addr uri is " + res.toString());

    return res;
}
@SuppressLint("NewApi") 
private static long getOrCreateThreadId(Context context, String recipients) throws Exception
{

    return 11;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Android 4.4 only default message app can write to sms and mms content resolvers, so maybe you tried on device with Android 4.4 or older
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html